SharePoint Subscription modern group view reduce groups to display
Most articles deal with how to increase the number of groups to display per page in SharePoint Subscription Edition modern views. I have the opposite problem. I am grouping by two fields and have chosen to display 10 groups per page (collapsed) and then Number of items to display in batches to 10. The number of groups to display appears to be ignored. Is this a bug or am I missing something within the modern view? Note: if I switch to Classic view, it works, and I see the pagination at the bottom for both the page view and the items.
Thank you!

It turns out that this is normal behavior. All items will show as you move down the page and the pagination is only for the classic experience. Simplify by picking some filters from the onset.
